# How to prove of $\lim \frac{1}{|x|+1}=0$ as $x$ goes to $-\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity

I understand that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{|x|+1}=0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0 $ and I choose $M>0$ such that $\frac{1}{M+1}<\varepsilon$. Thus, if $x\geq M$ then
$$\left|\frac{1}{|x|+1}\right|= \frac{1}{|x|+1}=\frac{1}{x+1}\leq \frac{1}{M+1}<\varepsilon.$$

But I cannot figure out how to prove that  $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{1}{|x|+1}=0$.

How can you prove this case? Any hints or tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Another way to see that it must be true in this case is to note that $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(-x)$, and in this case $f(-x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x <-M$ then  $|x| >M$ so $\frac  1 {|x|+1} <\frac 1 {M+1} <\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh! I see it now. Thanks :)